# StackExchange.Redis: one of Redis command not found

Tags: stackexchange.redis

There is a command in Redis named "Keys", when given a pattern, you can get all the matching keys.
But I can't find it in StackExchange.Redis.
Could anybody kindly tell me where I can find this command in StackExchange.Redis?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/KeysScan.md

This command (for reasons discussed in the link) is a server command, not a database command, and is available via `GetServer(...).Keys(...)`.